# Compare CSV in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

How can be compared two csv's , looking for the lines from `file_1.csv` that isn't repeated in `file_2.csv` and print it to a file?  (pandas was intended to use):

```
import pandas as pd
original = pd.read_csv('file_1.csv', sep=';')
backup = pd.read_csv('file_2.csv', sep=';')
n = pd.concat([original,backup], axis=0)
n.drop_duplicates(keep='first', inplace=True)
n.to_csv('diff.csv', sep=';')

File_1.csv
A00;A01;B01
A10;A11;B12
A20;A21;B22
....

File_2.csv 
A00;A01;B01
A20;A21;B22

diff.csv  [Real]
A00;A01;B01
A20;A21;B22

diff.csv  [Expected]
A10;A11;B12
```

This is getting me the whole bunch of lines that are repeated between the two files, not the absent lines in file_2 that are in file_1.

These are files of big size and big number of lines.
Thanks

Comment: You haven't provided a [mcve] with sample input and output, so we cant definitively answer but it sounds like you can get there using the `how=` parameter in pandas merge

Comment: line `A10;A11;B12` isn't repeated in `File_2`; why don't you expect it in the output?

Comment: Because there would be no differences between the original and the backup, so Im looking for the lost lines, not the ones saved.

Comment: Isn't that line lost?

Comment: I don't understand.  Maybe try to clarify your question.

Comment: @gmds , yes that line is lost, so Im trying to gather all the lost lines.

Comment: Then why do you say that your expected file is empty?

Comment: @gmds, you are right I edited the post.

Comment: Is it possible that there will be rows in the backup that are not in the original? What should be done in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pd.concat` will not work here, since you cannot tell whether a row which exists in the result came from the original or the backup. Instead, you should use `pd.merge` on all the columns with `indicator=True`, which basically performs an outer join, while telling you whether each row was present in both `DataFrames`:

```py
>>> merged = df1.merge(df2, how='outer', on=list(df1.columns), indicator=True)
>>> merged
     0    1    2     _merge
0  A00  A01  B01       both
1  A10  A11  B12  left_only
2  A20  A21  B22       both
```

We can then filter and drop the `_merge` column to get what we would expect in the result:

```py
>>> result = merged[merged['_merge'] == 'left_only'].drop(columns=['_merge'])
>>> result
     0    1    2
1  A10  A11  B12
```